# error occurred while setting the datasource for the report in CRM 2011

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

This error happens when try to add my SSRS report into CRM Dynamics

error occurred while setting the datasource for the report

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, for me when I changed the name of the Data Source to 'MSCRM_DataSource'(the name of my shared data source which my report was using it) it worked fine.